# how to implement an array of Boolean values, indexed by integers 2 to n

Tags: python

I don't know how to get an array of Boolean values, indexed by integers 2 to n.

I tried the following code, and it works, but I think it is stupid, and there must be something better. By the way, I first thought I don't need to write the very first two insert calls, but it seems in python that even if I write exactly insert(2, True), python will just put True in my first element of the array, in other words, a[0] = True not a[2] = True.

```
a = []
a.insert(0, 1)
a.insert(1, 1)
for index in range(2, n + 1):
    a.insert(index, True)
```

I am seeking for another easy and inspiring way to implement this [an array of Boolean values, indexed by integers 2 to n]

Edit: I tried to write the pseudocode from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes,

```
Input: an integer n > 1.

Let A be an array of Boolean values, indexed by integers 2 to n,
initially all set to true.

for i = 2, 3, 4, ..., not exceeding √n:
    if A[i] is true:
        for j = i2, i2+i, i2+2i, i2+3i, ..., not exceeding n:
           A[j] := false.

Output: all i such that A[i] is true.
```

as you can see, I just need a list that starts at index 2. I know how to do this algorithm, but I just felt that my way of creating [an array of Boolean values, indexed by integers 2 to n] is not good.

Comment: Would be more efficient to use a `bytearray` with some binary arithmetic.

Comment: If you want to create a list of true, you can use `a = [True]*(n+1)`. I don't follow what you're trying to do with the first two inserts.

Comment: Or use a list comprehension? `a + [True for i in range(n)]`

Comment: What is your use case ? It looks very strange to start an array at index 2. You can write your own class wraping the list type to make it accessible through `m = MyclassMyclass(); m.insert(True)` and `m[2]` -> return the first element of what is contained inside m.

Comment: Not directly related to your problem, but: when you want to add a new element to the right end of a list, prefer `.append` over `.insert`. Also keep in mind that your `a` value there is a list and not an array. You may have trouble finding accurate information about the respective types if you get their names mixed up.

Comment: Re. pseudocode: it doesn't *say* a non-associative array is needed. :P An [associative array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) (aka a dictionary) will probably work just as well (although with additional space overhead).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python lists are always indexing from zero. If you want to create a list with True's from 2 to N, you can create something like this:

```
N = 5
a = [None] * 2 + [True] * (N-2)
```

> `[None, None, True, True, True]`

And use only indices 2 or more later in your code.

Comment: OK, I think your answer is a better idea.